# Creating a alert box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a beginner in web designing and i have designed a contact page for which the page coding is:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4 class="uppercase weight-700">Send us a message</h4>
            <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="first_name">Tell us your name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Tell us your email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telephone">What&#39;s your number?</label>
                        <input type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comments">Give us the details</label>
                        <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="28" rows="6"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <br/>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Send Message </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the php code is (send_form_email.php):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "email@mydomain.com";
    $email_subject = "Form Data";
    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
   $string_exp = /^[0-9]+$/';
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The telephone you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php
}
?>
```

When the user clicks on submit button, he is redirected to send_form_email.php page. Now I just want that in place of user going to another page, both the error message and success message should be display on the same page in alert box.

Comment: Why not just do an onload even on your send_from_email.php page to throw an alert/error on page load?

Comment: You are looking for an AJAX call: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. you can make the form submit to the same page i.e set the form action to the same as the page as the form and then handle the form data. Once you have the errors you can display them as appropriate. This would mean to have the html and php on the same page which is not the cleanest option.
2. Use ajax to submit the form using jQuery. This might be intimidating since you've just started out.  Though this would be a cleaner and smoother way of doing it as it would not involve a page refresh.

it would be something like :

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

[Jquery Ajax Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

jQuery is not all that hard to pick up and would be a good tool to learn.

Answer (score 0):

When the page paints out, do this:

```
<script>
alert(<? echo $error_message ?>);
</script>
```

Any of the PHP variables that you set on the page can be used in place if where I put "$error_message"